# How to get a white border in frames?

Tags: home

I want to have an image with a white border, just like this:

[image]

I asked the seller, if the image comes with a white border.
He said, it does not have a white border.

The poster size is 45cm x 60cm. I guess for a 2cm border, I would need buy a customized frame of size 49x64cm? Or would this not work, as the poster may glitch down?

Comment: Does "glitch down" mean you have to print it yourself, or do they supply an actual poster? If the latter, you either frame the picture behind a cardboard mount, or in front of a flat backing paper. If the former you edit it into a new image with a border before printing it. And "the poster size is x". A digital image does not have a physical size (only the pixels): you print it to the size of paper you want, and the printing software hopefully takes care of it.

Comment: They supply the poster, I can't print it. BUt this approach is very uncommen right? Because I don't seem to find any poster frames that are slightly larger then 45x60

Answer (score 2):

Typically prints and paintings are mounted with one or more "mats" covering their edges.
This produces the white (or other colour) border.

An alternative is to secure the poster to a white foam board that fits the frame but is larger than the poster.
The visible part of the foam board will provide the border.

See [How to Frame a Poster](https://www.framedestination.com/blog/diy/how-to-frame-a-poster) (or web search for "matting a poster") for various ideas.

Here's an excessive example of 5 layers of matting (on a print that already had a white border):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The 'Just Picture This' Lifehack.**

Normally, posters are printed and trimmed 'bleeding four sides' (edge to edge) on a special 'sheet-fed' printing press.

Larger prints such as this may 'glitch' (slide) down in a frame over time unless there is sufficient pressure to hold it in place by the glass and the frame back.
When a thin border is used (as it is here), any displacement of the piece in the frame will be very obvious. The eye is very good at seeing uneven spacing by comparison of one edge to its close neighbour. Just seeing a picture frame that is not level will be noticeable.

Use of a white matte may also increase the thickness of the composition for some stability.

If the poster is not a valuable collector's edition, archival tape can be used to hold the piece in place from the rear. If it is a collectable, I would get a professional to mount the poster for you.

Good Luck